# create file oustside default directory php

Tags: php, makefile, filesystems

I am creating file using

```
$myfile = fopen($scriptname.'.sh', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Now, how do I save this to a specific directory `"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Scriptor\User-Generated-Scripts"` ?

Currently the files are saved to my default php directory.
Couldn't find an example where filename is a variable ($scriptname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write to any directory in PHP, you need to use the full directory address in the `fopen` method. Secondly, to create a file if it does not exist, use `w+` as the second parameter in the `fopen` method.

```
<?php
    $filename = fopen("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Scriptor\User-Generated-Scripts\test_script.sh", "w+") or die("Unable to open or create file!");

    fwrite($filename, 'echo "Hello World!"');

    fclose($filename);
```

Note: The PHP file and directory you are writing to still need the correct permissions to allow it. Also PHP's `fopen` cannot create non-existent directories, so you will need to make a check using the `is_dir` method for false, and then potentially use the `mkdir` method to create the directory.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I dont have the filename, I create the filename using user input on variable $scriptname. I tried below, but this dont work. Whatever you suggested when I use the filename directly instead of variable.

$myfile = fopen("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Scriptor\User-Generated-Scripts\$scriptname.'.sh'", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");

Comment: Your quotes at the end of the fopen function are messed up a little. You're trying to end a double quote `"` with a dot and single quote `.'` after the `$scriptname`. You don't need to do this since you are building the string using double quotes to begin with. E.g. fopen("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Scriptor\User-Generated-Scripts\$scriptname.sh", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");

https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/